# JavaScript: How to solve this race condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, race-condition

I have a UI that allows sorting of an `ul` of `li`. For that I use jQuery-UI's `sortable`. However, the sorting is disabled by default and only activated on click of a button. At the same time, I have a click-event on each li, that displays a preview of the paragraph the li is representing on the sorting screen. This works fine, except that if I am actively sorting, the click event is also being triggered.

What happens is, every time I sort an `li`, I automatically see a preview, which i don't want to happen. What I have done to prevent it is the following: The click-event is only triggered if the `li` misses the class `no_preview`. That class is added to the `li` whenever I start sorting, and removed whenever sorting completed.

```
jQuery('ul.wiki_ul_layout_coloumns>li:not(.no_preview)').live('click', function() {
   //show preview
})

jQuery('ul.wiki_ul_layout_coloumns').sortable({
   connectWith: 'ul.wiki_ul_layout_coloumns',
   start: function(event, ui) {
      jQuery(ui.item).addClass('no_preview');
   },
   stop: function(event, ui) {
      jQuery(ui.item).removeClass('no_preview');
   }
});
```

Testing this new solution, I saw that I have created a race condition (since both react on a keyup). Now, I could solve this by adding a timer to `jQuery(ui.item).removeClass('no_preview')` but I consider that solution to be more of a hack. Is there a proper way (or at least a nicer way) to solve this problem?

#### EDIT 1

I have updated the code to show that I use multiple lists which are interconnected. Up until now I thought it was irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: There might be a problem with the misspelled columns in 'ul.wiki_ul_layout_coloumns'?

Comment: Which version of jquery.ui are you using? On 1.8.7 I cannot reproduce this. Even without the no_preview hack it won't fire the click for me.

Comment: I use jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.4 + jQuery UI 1.8.6. It won't fire you say... hmm, maybe it has more to do with the interconnected lists? I'll update the question to include that bit of code too.

Comment: Good thing you added that. Seems like a bug was fixed concerning connected lists. Look at the release notes for 1.8.7 under sortable: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Changelog/1.8.7

Comment: It worked with the jQuery-UI update. Could you write this as an answer so I can accept it? ;)

Comment: More specifically, it was this bug http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug was fixed concerning connected lists. Look at the release notes for 1.8.7 under sortable: jqueryui.com/docs/Changelog/1.8.7

If you would have been stuck with 1.8.6 or less you could probably have haacked around it by adding a event.preventImmediatePropagation() in the stop event handler. Not sure though as I haven't tested it, but it should work in theory.